# java server daemon deployment options

Tags: java, daemon

I have written a small tcp server daemon in Java which is executed using the following code:

```
TCPServer serv = new TCPServer();
serv.run();
```

Now, I want to take this code from development into enterprise deployment, however, as I am not familiar with enterprise Java, I was wondering how to best possibly deploy this application as a production ready daemon.

I have tried to think what I really need and the answer is:

- Start the server
- Stop a running server
- Check if the server is still running
- Restart the service (I guess this one is easy given the other ones)
- Refresh the daemon configuration without service disruption

Furthermore, I might want/need to send specific commands to the service during runtime to modify the behaviour slightly, but this is of less importance at the moment.

I have some experience with servlet containers, but I am kind of loss once the application is not longer a http/https service.

Are there any best practices for how to deploy and manage such Java-based services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to tailor this to the OS I'm in and company conventions, but generally, putting the files in `/opt/my-project` and an init script in `/etc/init.d` (or similar). The init script follow's the OS's conventions, has a pid file, etc.

Comment: But how do you ensure that your Java app can respond to for instance a request to refresh the configuration or gracefully shut down? For unix processes you can use signals to ask the process to refresh its configuration or to gracefully shut down, but thats for unix only...

Comment: Shutdown is easy; add a [shutdown hook](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook(java.lang.Thread)) that tidily closes resources. Right; signals are Unix-only, and I don't think there's a way to handle signals without using Sun-internal code, but you could use JMX, a socket, an embedded webserver, a named pipe, etc.